# mandar de un js del lado del front a uno en back

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, express, backend

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con unos compañeros y somos principio de junior por lo que tenemos muchos problemas, estamos montando una aplicación con Node, express, body-parse... El problema que nos encontramos es que tenemos archivos js estáticos para el front donde realizamos diferentes funciones, ahora nos interesa enviar información: variables!! al back y no damos con la tecla, he visto que lo normal sería utilizar AJAX pero no sabemos por ahora utilizarlo y estamos trabajando con Form Post.

Este seria el código en js estatico del front

```
// Obtener fecha
let date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
document.getElementById('outTra1').innerHTML = date.toLocaleDateString();

// Obtener hora
var currentTime = new Date();

currentTime.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(currentTime.toLocaleTimeString());
document.getElementById('outTra2').innerHTML = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString();

// Obtener dirección
console.log(routes[0].name);
document.getElementById('outTra3').innerHTML = routes[0].name;

// Obtener nºTrayecto
console.log(uuid.v4());
const traking = uuid.v4();
document.getElementById('outTra').innerHTML = traking;
```

Este seria en endPoint

```
router.post("/Factura", user.factura);
```

y aqui seria donde quiero utilizarlo que es el js de lado del servidor

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');
const user = require('../controllers/user.controllers');



function crearPDF(dataCallBack, endCallback) {
const nombre = 'Nombre:   Paco';
const apellido = 'Apellido:   Suarez';
const DNI = 'D.N.I:        58392087F';

const doc = new PDFDocument({  size: 'A4', margin: 50 });
doc.on('data',dataCallBack);
doc.on('end',endCallback);
       doc.image('/Users/javi/Desktop/Introduccion_bootcamp/Backend/ProyectoFullBack/views/css   /logo.png', 50, 50, {
     width: 130,
        height: 150,
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'center'
    });

    doc.fontSize(25).text(nombre, 200, 135);
    doc.fontSize(25).text(apellido, 200, 155);
    doc.fontSize(25).text(DNI, 200, 175);




    doc.fontSize(25).text('Nº de trayecto', 20, 300);
    
    doc.end();
 }

 


module.exports = { crearPDF };
```

Comment: Ya he conseguido hacer mediante Fetch desde el js de front el envío de una variable

Comment: con este fetch                                                               

    const todo = {
      title: 'Some really important work to finish'
     };
    document.getElementById('botonF').addEventListener('click',  () => {

   fetch('http://localhost:3000/Factura', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(todo),
   })
   })

Answer (score 0):

Para recibir la informacion de un form en el servidor de Node debes estar a la escucha de requests, las cuales traeran como payload los valores que se ingresaron en la aplicacion cliente. No veo en tu codigo donde estas esperando recibir esos datos.

Comment: si el problema es ese... intenta ponerle el código tú, las respuestas deben ser concretas completas y resolver el problema, decir lo que tiene que hacer no soluciona el problema si no le das la solución.